# Growth factor Gaussian elimination

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, matlab, gaussian-elimination

I'm looking at the exercises in the book "Numerical Linear Algebra" by Trefethen and Bau. I'm quite stuck at question 22.2:

Experiment with solving $60\times60$ systems of equations $Ax=b$ by Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting, with $A$ having the form (22.4). Do you observe that the results are useless because of the growth factor of order $2^{60}$? At first attempt you may not observe this, because the integer entries of $A$ may prevent any rounding errors from occurring. If so, find a way to modify your problem slightly so that the growth factor is the same or nearly so and catastrophic rounding errors really do take place.

I coded Gaussian elimination with partial pivoting in MATLAB and everything seems fine. However, when I try to do the above exercise, I don't get the results one would expect.

- For starters: there are rounding errors in the LU decomposition even when A only has integer values (since the growth factor is $2^{59}$, MATLAB can't represent the largest values in $U$ exactly).
- Even weirder: when I perturb $A$ such that the values are not all integer, the solution of the system is better and not worse at all (for the same right-hand-side).

I'm not sure why this happens, or what I'm doing wrong. Hopefully one of you knows why.

Comment: Once again, why closing this interesting and well written question ? Is the person who has considered that this question should be closed is seeing numerical linear algebra such as LU decomposition as "bad mathematics" ?

Comment: It's hard to see how this question can be answered here I'm afraid.  First, you haven't provided enough details (when was the book written?  Programs like MATLAB have progressed significantly over the years, and easily-available computing power has changed).  Second, this isn't a MATLAB site so we can't do more than speculate on why you're seeing rounding errors.  You could try asking on a MATLAB forum though -- but they'll probably ask for a minimal code example, which would be off-topic here.  Your last bullet-point might be answerable if you provided more specific details though.